# Intuition behind filter on a set

Tags: intuition, filters

In "Counter-examples in topology" of Steen and Seebach, they define a filter on a set $X$ is a collection F of subsets of $X$ with the following properties:

1. Every subset of $X$ which contains a set of $F$ belongs to $F$
2. Every finite intersection of sets of $F$ belongs to $F$
3. $\varnothing$ is **not** in $F$

My question is: what is the intuition behind this definition?

Comment: "Measure" $1$. Measure is in quotes since it is in general only finitely additive.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Generally each filter encodes a possible meaning of what it means for a subset of $X$ to be "large enough" or "contain enough points" for something.

In addition to Asaf's examples, other good filters to keep in mind are

1. The *principal filter* of $x\in X$, which is the set of all subsets of $X$ that contain $x$. Here "large enough" is almost trivial, being large enough just means to contain $x$.
2. The *neighborhood filter* of $x$, when $X$ is a topological space. This is the set of all subsets of $X$ that have $x$ as an *interior point*.

These example show that being "large" or (in Asaf's words) including "most" elements can be very context dependent and doesn't need to correspond to "most" in an objective sense.

---

The neighborhood filter is particularly important because it is the prototype of the use of filters to *generalize the notion of limits*. Filters are one possible answer to what kind of thing does "$x\to 5$" in $\lim\limits_{x\to 5} f(x)$ stand for.

For example, when $\mathcal F$ is a filter in $X$ and $f$ is some function defined on $X$, we can define $$\lim_{x\to\mathcal F} f(x)=y \text{ means that } \forall \varepsilon>0\, \exists F\in\mathcal F\, \forall x\in F : |f(x)-y|<\varepsilon$$ 
If we choose $\mathcal F$ to be the punctured-neighborhood filter at $5$ gives us the usual limit for $x\to 5$. But there are other filters that give one-sided limits ($x\to 5^+$ corresponds to the filter of all sets that contain $(5,5+\delta]$ for some $\delta>0$) or limits involving infinity ($x\to-\infty$ corresponds to the filter of all sets that contain $(-\infty,y]$ for some $y\in\mathbb R$), and so forth, which can now be considered instances of a single uniform concept.

Comment: thank you good sir! you are a gentleman and a scholar

Answer (score 25):

Filters come to model the notion of "large sets", or subsets which include "most" of the elements of $X$.

1. Most elements of $X$ are in $X$; and most elements are *not* in $\varnothing$.
2. If most elements are in $A$ and most elements are in $B$, then most elements are in $A\cap B$.
3. If most elements are in $A$, and $A\subseteq B$, then of course that most elements are in $B$.

Examples for "most" can be seen in the canonical examples, the cofinite filter, namely $\mathcal F=\{A\subseteq X\mid X\setminus A\text{ is finite}\}$. Then every $A\in\mathcal F$ includes most of the elements of $X$ in this aspect.

Similarly, $\{A\subseteq[0,1]\mid m(A)=1\}$ where $m$ is the Lebesgue measure, also gives us a filter on $[0,1]$ which give us subsets which are almost everything in terms of measure.

Comment: by "most of" do you mean all but finitely many?

Comment: No. That's just an example of what "most" means in a lot of contexts, but that's definitely not the only meaning.

Answer (score 1):

My intuition for a filter is very literal. I imagin you have a set of elements $S$ and you send them though "actual filters" and recive some outputs i.e. subsets of the original set $A \subset S$. The thing we call filter $X$ is then the collection of subsets ("actual filters") of the original set $X \subset P(S)$ (where $P(S)$ denotes the power set of $S$).

The filter $X$ describes a collection of "actual filters" that fulfill a certain property. Thus every "actual filter" $A$ in $X$ should **at least** contain the elements from the original set $S$ we are interested in when considering the filter $X$. So the complement of "actual filters" contains elements we are not interested in (you can show the fact: $A \in X \implies A^c \not\in X$ only from the definition of filters).

Now the interpretation of the definition of filters:

1. Clearly $S$ has to be in the filter $X$, because the element(s) we are interested in are certainly in $S$. And with the same notinon $\emptyset$ is not in our filter because the "actual filter" $\emptyset$ filters out all elements, thus also the ones we are interested in.
2. If we have two "actual filters" $A$ and $B$ in our collection $X$, then they both contain the elements we are interested in (i.e. only filter out elements we do not care about) thus the intercection of these "actual filters" $A\cap B$ also contains the elements we are interested in, so $A \cap B$ is in $X$.
3. Suppose $A$ is a "actual filter" in our collection $X$ then every superset of $A$ also filters out the elements we are interested in. For every set $B$ the union $A \cup B$ is a superset of $A$. So $A \cup B$ is in $X$.

This interpretation breaks abaprt a bit, if you consider Frechet filters which contain sets that have finite complements. Instead of spesific elements, the Frechet filter describes "actual filters" that only filter out a finite amount of elements.

Ultrafilters $U$ would then be the maximal collection of "actual filters" that filter out elements with a certain property associated to our filter.